# Showing a stage from the Main class in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm new to javafx and I need your help. I searched on internet but no success... So, I am trying to make a dialog appear when I use the jar for the first time. To do this, I tried to test if a certain property existed in a file and if so, launch the "first time dialog". When I click "ok" on this dialog, I will save the property to the file. The only problem, the primaryStage is the "main window" not the first time one. This dialog has a controller so when I'm in the "setOnAction method" of the button, I can't launch the primaryStage. I can't use the "node.getWindow.getScene" (or something like that) method because it isn't opened yet, the user is still in the "first time window". Here is my code..

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("real.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("LoL Ready To Win");
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

    try {

        input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
        prop.load(input);

        if(prop.getProperty("name") != null){
            primaryStage.show();
        }else if(prop.getProperty("name") == null){

            try {
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                Parent root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("summ.fxml"));
                stage.setTitle("Insert Title Here");
                stage.setResizable(false);
                stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
                stage.show();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the controller

```
submit.setOnAction(e->{
    if (summfield.getText() == null || summfield.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Temp title");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("Please enter a valid name!");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }else{
        try {

            output = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");

            prop.setProperty("name", summfield.getText());

            prop.store(output, null);

        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (output != null) {
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException a) {
                    a.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        // And this is where I wanna launch the primaryStage
    }

});
```

If you have any advice even if it's not an answer to my question, I appreciate it! Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller for summ.fxml, do:

```
public class SummController {

    private String name ;

    public String getName() {
        return name ;
    }

    public void initialize() {

        submit.setOnAction(e->{
            if (summfield.getText() == null || summfield.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert.setTitle("Temp title");
                alert.setHeaderText(null);
                alert.setContentText("Please enter a valid name!");
                alert.showAndWait();
            }else{
                try {

                    name = summfield.getText();

                    output = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");

                    prop.setProperty("name", name);

                    prop.store(output, null);

                    submit.getScene().getWindow().hide();

                } catch (IOException io) {
                    io.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (output != null) {
                        try {
                            output.close();
                        } catch (IOException a) {
                            a.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

        });
    }

}
```

Now modify the start method as:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("real.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("LoL Ready To Win");
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

    try {

        input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
        prop.load(input);

        if(prop.getProperty("name") != null){
            primaryStage.show();
        }else if(prop.getProperty("name") == null){

            try {
                Stage stage = new Stage();

                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("summ.fxml"));
                Parent root1 = loader.load();

                stage.setTitle("Insert Title Here");
                stage.setResizable(false);
                stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));

                stage.showAndWait();

                // if you need the input:
                SummController summController = loader.getController();
                String name = summController.getName();
                // do something with name...

                primaryStage.show();

            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: It seems to work fine but the only problem is that if the input doesn't exist, it gives an error. I will try to check if it exist too... I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: Thanks so much ! This worked perfectly. I added a "if(file.exists()) before the input declaration. Like this it is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you change the order of your launch something like this:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("real.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("LoL Ready To Win");
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

    try {

        input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
        prop.load(input);

        if(prop.getProperty("name") == null){               
            try {
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                Parent root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("summ.fxml"));
                stage.setTitle("Insert Title Here");
                stage.setResizable(false);
                stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
                stage.showAndWait();

                input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
                prop.load(input);
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        primaryStage.show();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your show once window write out your property?